# How to update and save user metadata on page visits?

Tags: php, user-meta, meta-value

Basically I'm looking for something like this:

```
<?php if ( is_page( array( 'home' ) ) ): ?>
        
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'pagehome', '1' );
        
<?php else: ?>
            
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'pagehome', '0' );

<?php endif; ?>
```

I want to change usermeta data for current user depending on which page  they visited.

So I need to find a simple code to fire     `update_user_meta( $user_id, 'pagehome', '1' );` and record into database.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of actions you can hook into to do this, I think the best once to use would be `wp` or `template_redirect`.

Using either of those actions the code would be like this, this code goes into the `functions.php`

```
add_action('wp', 'bt_update_user_homepage_meta');
function bt_update_user_homepage_meta () {
    // get user id, if user is not logged in then it will be 0
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    // now we check if we are in front page or not and we update the user meta accordingly
    // if user is not logged in this code will try to update the meta for user 0,
    // because this user doesn't exist, nothing will happen
    if (is_front_page()) update_user_meta($user_id, 'pagehome', '1');
    else update_user_meta($user_id, 'pagehome', '0');
}
```

Comment: hey Buttered_Toast, I have added your code to my `fuctions.php` and browsed myself a bit on my website, however, when I try to echo the value with: `<?php $user_id = wp_get_current_user(); echo get_the_author_meta('pagehome', $user_id); ?>` I don't see any values outputted. A blank. Does the record really stores into db? I'm new to coding myself.

Comment: `wp_get_current_user()` return a user object, not the user id, it containes the id but if you only want the user id use `get_current_user_id()`. Also `get_the_author_meta()` will not return `pagehome` because it doesn't contain it, use this `get_user_meta($user_id, 'pagehome', true)`

Comment: Thanks! I do see the values now. They are actually stored! THANKS!